# NHibernate not filling set but SQL is correct

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Consider the following mapping:

```
<class name="Articulo" table="Articulos">
 <id name="Id" column="IdArticulo"/>
 <set name="CodigosProveedor" inverse="true" fetch="select">
  <key>
    <column name="IdArticulo"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="ArticuloProveedor"/>
 </set>
 <set name="PuntosPedido" inverse="true" fetch="select">
  <key column="IdArticulo" foreign-key="IdArticulo"/>
  <one-to-many class="PuntoPedido"/>
 </set>
 ...
</class>

<class name="PuntoPedido" table="PersISAVAL_SPCO_Previsiones_PuntosPedidoMes">
 <composite-id>
  <key-many-to-one name="Articulo" column="IdArticulo"/>
  <key-many-to-one name="Color" column="IdColor"/>
  <key-many-to-one name="Proveedor" column="IdProveedor"/>
 </composite-id>
 <property name="Valor" column="PuntoPedido"/>
</class>

<class name="ArticuloProveedor" table="Prov_Articulos">
 <composite-id>
  <key-property name="IdArticulo" column="IdArticulo"/>
  <key-property name="IdProveedor" column="IdProveedor"/>
 </composite-id>
 <property name="LeadTimeForzado" column="PlazoAprovisionamiento"/>
 <property name="IdEstadoHomologacion" column="Estado_Homologacion"/>
 <many-to-one name="Articulo" column="IdArticulo"/>
 <many-to-one name="Proveedor" column="IdProveedor"/>
</class>
```

And then the call:

```
         _session.QueryOver<Articulo>()
            .Where(e => e.ProveedorPreferencial == p)
            .Fetch(a => a.CodigosProveedor).Eager
            .Future();
         _session.QueryOver<Articulo>()
           .Where(a => a.ProveedorPreferencial == p)
           .Fetch(a => a.PuntosPedido).Eager
           .Future();
```

The returned SQL statement seems correct for both properties, however, `CodigosProveedor` gets properly loaded but `PuntosPedido` remains empty. Why is this happening?

SQL Statements, they look apparently the same:

```
SELECT this_.IdArticulo                           as IdArti1_4_1_,
   this_.Descrip                              as Descri2_4_1_,
   this_.IdProveedorPreferencial              as IdPro11_4_1_,
   puntospedi2_.IdArticulo                    as IdArt1_53_3_,
   puntospedi2_.IdColor                       as IdCol2_53_3_,
   puntospedi2_.IdProveedor                   as IdPro3_53_3_,
   puntospedi2_.IdArticulo                    as IdArt1_53_0_,
   puntospedi2_.IdColor                       as IdCol2_53_0_,
   puntospedi2_.IdProveedor                   as IdPro3_53_0_,
   puntospedi2_.PuntoPedido                   as Punto4_53_0_
  FROM   Articulos this_
   inner join Conf_Articulos this_1_
     on this_.IdArticulo = this_1_.IdArticulo
   left outer join PersISAVAL_SPCO_Previsiones_PuntosPedidoMes puntospedi2_
     on this_.IdArticulo = puntospedi2_.IdArticulo
  WHERE  this_.IdProveedorPreferencial = '01816';

SELECT this_.IdArticulo                           as IdArti1_4_1_,
   this_.Descrip                              as Descri2_4_1_,
   this_.IdProveedorPreferencial              as IdPro11_4_1_,
   codigospro2_.IdArticulo                    as IdArt1_51_3_,
   codigospro2_.IdProveedor                   as IdPro2_51_3_,
   codigospro2_.IdArticulo                    as IdArt1_51_0_,
   codigospro2_.IdProveedor                   as IdPro2_51_0_,
   codigospro2_.PlazoAprovisionamiento        as Plazo3_51_0_,
   codigospro2_.Estado_Homologacion           as Estad4_51_0_
  FROM   Articulos this_
   inner join Conf_Articulos this_1_
     on this_.IdArticulo = this_1_.IdArticulo
   left outer join Prov_Articulos codigospro2_
     on this_.IdArticulo = codigospro2_.IdArticulo
  WHERE  this_.IdProveedorPreferencial = '01816';
```

If I execute this SQL directly, it is not empty.

Comment: The call you show does not call anything. It does just declare two futures, without storing them in some variables for later execution. How do you trigger their execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this problem was caused due to one field that was primary key being null at some records.

NHibernate does not support this but it should at least give a hint of what is going on.